# Describe a map $f: S^2 \times S^2 \rightarrow S^4$ such that $f^{*}$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, knot-theory, k-theory

Here is the question:

Describe a map $f: S^2 \times S^2 \rightarrow S^4$ such that $f^{*}: \tilde{H^4}(S^4, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \tilde{H^4}(S^2 \times S^2, \mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism. Does there exist a map $g: S^4 \rightarrow S^2 \times S^2$  such that  $g^{*}: \tilde{H^4}(S^2 \times S^2, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \tilde{H^4}( S^4 , \mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism? Explain your answer.

Could anyone help me in solving this question, please?

Comment: Embed the disk $D^4$ in $S^2 \times S^2$ then let $f$ be the map $S^2 \times S^2 \rightarrow (S^2 \times S^2)/(S^2 \times S^2 - D^4) = S^4 $. This workds for general $n-$manifolds. Embed a disk $D = D^n$ in $M$ and consider $M \rightarrow M/(M-D) = S^n$. This map is an isomorphism on homology/cohomology iff $M$ is closed and orientable.

Comment: Essentially this is because if you have two closed and oriented $n-$manifolds $M$ and $N$, i.e choices of fundamental homology classes $[M]$ and $[N]$ then the $deg(f)$ of a map $f: M \rightarrow N$ can be defined as the integer so that $f_*([M]) = deg(f)[N]$, this works for cohomology aswell. Then there is a theorem that sum of local degrees is the degree of $f$.

Comment: Just correcting an error I made in my first comment, the induced map $M \rightarrow S^n$ is an isomorphism on the *top* cohomology/homology, obviously not on all homology groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know a bit about CW complexes, try to show that $S^2\times S^2$ has a cell decomposition with one 0-cell, two 2-cells which give $S^2\vee S^2$, and and 4-cell. For $S^4$ take the standard decomposition with a 0-cell and a 4-cell. Then consider the map $S^2\times S ^2\to S^4$ that collapses $S^2\vee S^2$ to the $0$-cell of $S^4$ and maps the remaining open 4-cell of $S^2\times S^2$ homeomorphically onto that of $S^4$. You should be able to study the effect of this map on the cellular complexes.

By the way, this is morally the same reasoning that Noel Lundström suggested in his comments, just without explicitly mentioning orientability.